# How to make the program not calculate the mathematical expression?

Tags: arrays, c

My friends and I invented this code where you write a list of numbers and every number meets a letter from the periodic table for example 1=H, 5=B and so on. Now a lot of elements have two letters symbols for example Db (Dubnium). If we want the letter D we write 105 (its atomic number) - 5 (the atomic number of B) and we get D. I wanted to write a program to decode these types of codes and here's how I did it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
    
int main()
{
    int k,i,x , size ,cif;
    int cifral[35];
    char litere[35];

    litere[1] = 'H';
    litere[5] = 'B';
    litere[6] = 'C';
    litere[7] = 'N';
    litere[8] = 'O';
    litere[9] = 'F';
    litere[15] = 'P';
    litere[16] = 'S';
    litere[19] = 'K';
    litere[23] = 'V';
    litere[105-5] = 'D';    

    printf("How many elements does your code has: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    for( i=0 ; i<size ; i++) // stocks the numbers into the array
    {
        scanf(" %d ",&cifral[i]);
    }

    for(k=0 ; k<size ; k++) //converts the numbers into letters
    {
        printf(" %c ",litere[cifral[k]]);
    } 
}
```

Here is my problem. Letter D should be 105-5 but the program calculates it and you get D when you type 100, when you introduce 105-5 I get a random thing like a division sign. How can I do so when I type 105-5 I get D for example.

Comment: `char litere[35]; litere[105-5] = 'D';` is out-of-bounds write, which is dangerous.

Comment: Using array index as the atomic number in this case is not a right approach, that's all. You need a different data structure.

Comment: Do you mean `105 - 5 = 100`, or the string "105-5"?

Comment: _"we write 105(its Atomic number)-5(the atomic number of B) and we get D"_ Eh?  Even if that made any kind of sense DB != Db.  Why not just use strings for the element symbol.

Comment: `scanf("%d"` is not going to recognize a string like "105-5" as an input. You'll need a custom input parsing mechanism.

Comment: _"my friends invented these code"_ - except you haven't have you?  You've invented an idea for code that you don't know how to write.

Comment: @Clifford OP has certainly invented [a code](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/code) and is hoping to also code up some code to decode the code.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not associative maps:

```
litere[105-5] = 'D';
```

means that the element 100 of the array `litere` is set to to `D`.  It does not associate the value 105 with `Db` (that would be weird).  Moreover, of course `litere` only has 35 elements in any case.

When you type the *string* `"105-5"`, the `scanf()` `%d` format specifier reads 105 (it stops interpreting at the `-` - it certainly won't parse an arithmetic expression!).  Apart from that the whole premise makes no logical sense.

A solution that makes more sense is to use a simple lookup-table such as:

```
static const char* periodic_table[] =
{   NULL,
    "H",  "He", "Li", "Be", "B",  "C",  "N",  "O", 
    "F",  "Ne", "Na", "Mg", "Al", "Si", "P",  "S", 
    "Cl", "Ar", "K",  "Ca", "Sc", "Ti", "V",  "Cr", 
    "Mn", "Fe", "Co", "Ni", "Cu", "Zn", "Ga", "Ge", 
    "As", "Se", "Br", "Kr", "Rb", "Sr", "Y",  "Zr", 
    "Nb", "Mo", "Tc", "Ru", "Rh", "Pd", "Ag", "Cd", 
    "In", "Sn", "Sb", "Te", "I",  "Xe", "Cs", "Ba", 
    "La", "Ce", "Pr", "Nd", "Pm", "Sm", "Eu", "Gd", 
    "Tb", "Dy", "Ho", "Er", "Tm", "Yb", "Lu", "Hf", 
    "Ta", "W",  "Re", "Os", "Ir", "Pt", "Au", "Hg", 
    "Tl", "Pb", "Bi", "Po", "At", "Rn", "Fr", "Ra", 
    "Ac", "Th", "Pa", "U",  "Np", "Pu", "Am", "Cm", 
    "Bk", "Cf", "Es", "Fm", "Md", "No", "Lr", "Rf", 
    "Db", "Sg", "Bh", "Hs", "Mt", "Ds", "Rg", "Cn", 
    "Nh", "Fl", "Mc", "Lv", "Ts", "Og" 
} ; 

#define MAX_ATOMIC_NUMBER (sizeof(periodic_table) / sizeof(*periodic_table) - 1)
```

which will *exhaustively* associate every element symbol with its respective atomic number.

Given such a table you might have:

```
const char* getElementSymbol( int atomic_number )
{
    if( atomic_number < 0 || atomic_number > MAX_ATOMIC_NUMBER )
    {
        atomic_number = 0 ;
    }

    return periodic_table[atomic_number] ;
}

int getAtomicNumber( const char* element_symbol )
{
    int atomic_number = 0 ;
    for( int i = 1; 
         atomic_number == 0 && i <= MAX_ATOMIC_NUMBER;
         i++ )
    {
        if( strcmp( element_symbol, periodic_table[i] ) == 0 )
        {
            atomic_number = i ;
        }
    }

    return atomic_number ;
}
```

Then you can use these functions to to get the atomic number of any element or the symbol for any atomic number.  The following loop "round-trips" the conversion from atomic number `a` to symbol `sym` then back to `atomic_number`:

```
for( int a = 1 ; a <= MAX_ATOMIC_NUMBER; a++ )
{
    const char* sym = getElementSymbol( a ) ;
    int atomic_number = getAtomicNumber( sym ) ;

    printf("%d -> %s -> %\n", a, sym, atomic_number ) ;
}
```

Outputting:

```
1 -> H -> 1
2 -> He -> 2
3 -> Li -> 3
4 -> Be -> 4
5 -> B -> 5
6 -> C -> 6
7 -> N -> 7
8 -> O -> 8
9 -> F -> 9
10 -> Ne -> 10
11 -> Na -> 11
12 -> Mg -> 12
13 -> Al -> 13
14 -> Si -> 14
15 -> P -> 15
16 -> S -> 16
17 -> Cl -> 17
18 -> Ar -> 18
19 -> K -> 19
20 -> Ca -> 20
21 -> Sc -> 21
22 -> Ti -> 22
23 -> V -> 23
24 -> Cr -> 24
25 -> Mn -> 25
26 -> Fe -> 26
27 -> Co -> 27
28 -> Ni -> 28
29 -> Cu -> 29
30 -> Zn -> 30
31 -> Ga -> 31
32 -> Ge -> 32
33 -> As -> 33
34 -> Se -> 34
35 -> Br -> 35
36 -> Kr -> 36
37 -> Rb -> 37
38 -> Sr -> 38
39 -> Y -> 39
40 -> Zr -> 40
41 -> Nb -> 41
42 -> Mo -> 42
43 -> Tc -> 43
44 -> Ru -> 44
45 -> Rh -> 45
46 -> Pd -> 46
47 -> Ag -> 47
48 -> Cd -> 48
49 -> In -> 49
50 -> Sn -> 50
51 -> Sb -> 51
52 -> Te -> 52
53 -> I -> 53
54 -> Xe -> 54
55 -> Cs -> 55
56 -> Ba -> 56
57 -> La -> 57
58 -> Ce -> 58
59 -> Pr -> 59
60 -> Nd -> 60
61 -> Pm -> 61
62 -> Sm -> 62
63 -> Eu -> 63
64 -> Gd -> 64
65 -> Tb -> 65
66 -> Dy -> 66
67 -> Ho -> 67
68 -> Er -> 68
69 -> Tm -> 69
70 -> Yb -> 70
71 -> Lu -> 71
72 -> Hf -> 72
73 -> Ta -> 73
74 -> W -> 74
75 -> Re -> 75
76 -> Os -> 76
77 -> Ir -> 77
78 -> Pt -> 78
79 -> Au -> 79
80 -> Hg -> 80
81 -> Tl -> 81
82 -> Pb -> 82
83 -> Bi -> 83
84 -> Po -> 84
85 -> At -> 85
86 -> Rn -> 86
87 -> Fr -> 87
88 -> Ra -> 88
89 -> Ac -> 89
90 -> Th -> 90
91 -> Pa -> 91
92 -> U -> 92
93 -> Np -> 93
94 -> Pu -> 94
95 -> Am -> 95
96 -> Cm -> 96
97 -> Bk -> 97
98 -> Cf -> 98
99 -> Es -> 99
100 -> Fm -> 100
101 -> Md -> 101
102 -> No -> 102
103 -> Lr -> 103
104 -> Rf -> 104
105 -> Db -> 105
106 -> Sg -> 106
107 -> Bh -> 107
108 -> Hs -> 108
109 -> Mt -> 109
110 -> Ds -> 110
111 -> Rg -> 111
112 -> Cn -> 112
113 -> Nh -> 113
114 -> Fl -> 114
115 -> Mc -> 115
116 -> Lv -> 116
117 -> Ts -> 117
118 -> Og -> 118
```

Or for the atomic numbers in your attempt:

```
int cifral[] = {1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 15, 16, 19, 23, 105 } ;
for( int k = 0 ; k < sizeof(cifral)/sizeof(*cifral); k++ )
{
    const char* sym = getElementSymbol( cifral[k] ) ;

    printf("%d\t%s\n", cifral[k], sym ) ;
}
```

```
1   H
5   B
6   C
7   N
8   O
9   F
15  P
16  S
19  K
23  V
105 Db
```

Comment: Your table of elements is out of date.  All the UuX elements now have regular 2-character names — see https://webelements.com/ for example; the names were finalized in 2016 by the IUPAC.  Element 113 was Uut but is now Nh Nihonium; element 115 was Uup but is now Mc Moscovium; element 117 was Uus but is now Ts Tennessine; and element 118 was Uuo but is now Og Oganesson.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. I copied the list from the first hit I got from a Google   Not really my problem and does not materially affect the answer.  Beats 105 = D ;-) Feel free to edit if you wish.  I may fix it but editing SO on a phone is not fun, so it will wait before I do it, if I can even be bothered.

Comment: I'd wait too if the alternative is editing on a phone.  It's annoying that some places that sell t-shirts with the periodic table haven't caught up with the change from nearly 5 years ago.  I'm here, I'll fix the UuX names.  I also took the liberty of aligning the data per row.

Comment: I have an SQL "table of elements" (and isotopes, etc) which I've maintained over a number of years.  Rg and Ds were assigned names circa 2009, Cn circa 2010, Fl and Lv circa 2012, and Nh, Mv, Ts and Og in 2016 — the approximate dates come from my change log for the file.

Comment: Meh, the table itself now has a half-life:)

Comment: @MartinJames — since Oganesson 118 completes the seventh period, it is relatively unlikely that the table will be extended into the eighth period any time soon.  In total, something like 3 atoms of Oganesson have been produced, one in 2002 and two in 2005.  See the link from Og on [Web Elements](https://webelements.com/).  The total number of atoms of Ts is similarly minimal.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Organesson?   Lemme guess, half-life in attoseconds:)

Comment: [Oganesson](https://www.webelements.com/oganesson/) says milliseconds rather than smaller units.  But definitely not stable.  And definitely only artificial.